# Sync WebApp GUI data automatically on backend state change

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I am looking for design and technology feasibility for an application where multiple users will be logging in into the application with a GUI showing there personal data and there will be a common dashboard GUI, which can show the consolidated state of all the users at a time. *The state changes in any of the user's data will get updated in Real Time to the GUI of all users.*

For Example, Say for an Online Cards Game, Each user can see there cards and make a choice to show the card to all or to increase the stake amount when there turn comes, and at the same time there will be a dashboard showing the current state of all the participants in the game. Now if any user shows a card, this change should be displayed to the DashBoard and other Participants, *they have not triggered any event or submitted any form from browser but the GUI needs an update, is there any JS Library to support this behaviour ?*

I am planning to use Spring MVC in the backend, most probably sitemesh for layout. The application design(design pattern) and JS framework are yet to be decided.

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

RSS Feed is a concept that seems to be helping to serve this purpose. I have recently found an abstract class : 'AbstractRssFeedView' that is supported by spring to implement RSS Feed.

This is the best possible approach  I have found so far for this problem, please suggest if you have any better approach ?